# Integral by partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$ \int \frac{5x}{\left(x-5\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ find the value of the constant when the antiderivative passes threw (6,0)

factor out the 5, and use partial fraction

$$ 5 \left[\int \frac{A}{x-5} + \frac{B}{\left(x-5\right)^2}\, \mathrm{d}x \right] $$

Solve for $A$ and $B$.

$A\left(x-5\right) + B = x$  Then $B-5A$ has to be zero and $A$ has to be 1.

Resulting in

$$ 5 \left[\int \frac{1}{x-5} + \frac{5}{\left(x-5\right)^2}\, \mathrm{d}x \right]$$

$$ \Rightarrow 5 \left[ \ln \vert x - 5 \vert -\frac{5}{x-5}\right] + C$$

However, this approach doesn't give the answer in the book.

**Book's Answer**

$$ \frac{5}{x-5} \left(\left(x-5\right) \ln \vert x - 5 \vert - x  \right) + C $$

The value should be 30, according to the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably they missed include a constant in book's answer.
If we include a constant $k$, the book's answer will change to:
$$\frac{5}{x-5}((x-5)\ln|x-5|-x)+k$$
But with some algebra we get
$$\frac{5}{x-5}((x-5)\ln|x-5|-x)+k=$$ $$=5(\frac{(x-5)}{x-5}\ln|x-5|-\frac{x}{x-5})+k= 5(\ln|x-5|-\frac{x}{x-5}+1)-5+k=$$ $$=5(\ln|x-5|-\frac{x}{x-5}+\frac{x-5}{x-5})-5+k=5(\ln|x-5|-\frac{5}{x-5})-5+k=$$
$$=5(\ln|x-5|-\frac{5}{x-5})+C$$
Which is your answer, where C is a new constant, such that $C=k-5$.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is correct, but books solution is also. Differentiate the solutions and you will see, that both of them are Antiderivatives.

Moreover it is:
$$ \frac{5}{x-5} \left(\left(x-5\right) \ln \vert x - 5 \vert - x  \right)
= 5 \left(\ln \vert x - 5 \vert - \frac{x-5+5}{x-5}\right) = 5 \left(\ln \vert x - 5 \vert - \frac{5}{x-5}\right) +\mathcal{Const}$$

Optional way to get your solution:
$$ \int \frac{5x}{\left(x-5\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x= \frac{5}{2}\int\frac{2x-10}{\left(x-5\right)^2}+\frac{10}{\left(x-5\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{5}{2}\left(2\ln\vert x-5\vert-\frac{10}{x-5}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: how does $x-5 + 5 = 5$?  Where did the $x$ goto?

Comment: @MaoYiyi: It is $\frac{x}{x-5} = \frac{x-5+5}{x-5} = 1+\frac{5}{x-5}$

Answer (score 3):

Distribute:
$$
\frac{5}{x-5}((x-5)\ln|x-5|-x)=5\left(\frac{x-5}{x-5}\ln|x-5|-\frac{x}{x-5}\right).
$$
Then
$$
\frac{x-5}{x-5}=1.
$$

Comment: I don't have the $x$ in the last fraction.

Comment: @MaoYiyi Sorry, didn't notice that.

Comment: @MaoYiyi RicardoCruz has the explanation.